# Cordova-plugin-file error while generating apk

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

**Error while generating APK**
*
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Installing "cordova-plugin-filepath" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.4.0, failed version requirement: 
      <6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-media" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-media': CordovaError: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@^6.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
    at /home/ritzylab/a/munshiji247-ionic/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:557:37
    at _fulfilled (/home/ritzylab/a/munshiji247-ionic/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/ritzylab/a/munshiji247-ionic/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/ritzylab/a/munshiji247-ionic/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /home/ritzylab/a/munshiji247-ionic/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:570:49
    at runSingle (/home/ritzylab/a/munshiji247-ionic/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/home/ritzylab/a/munshiji247-ionic/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@^6.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
*

**Cordova-plugin-list**

- cordova plugin list
  com.moust.cordova.videoplayer 1.0.1 "Video Player"
  cordova-plugin-battery-status 2.0.2 "Battery"
  cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
  cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
  cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
  cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
  cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
  cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
  cordova-plugin-filepath 1.0.2 "FilePath"
  cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
  cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
  cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.4.3 "Capture"
  cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
  cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
  cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
  cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
  cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.1.4-dev "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
  cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.4 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
  ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
  nl.x-services.plugins.videocaptureplus 1.0.0 "VideoCapturePlus"
  phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 7.1.2 "BarcodeScanner"
  phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.5 "PushPlugin"
  *

**Package.json**

```html
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/battery-status": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^4.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/media-capture": "^4.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/video-capture-plus": "^4.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/video-player": "^4.14.0",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/cordova-plugin-battery-status": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/cordova-plugin-media": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/ionic": "^3.19.0",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.9",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.6.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "backo2": "^1.0.2",
    "component-bind": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova": "^8.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "6.4.0",
    "cordova-ios": "~4.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-battery-status": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "~1.0.6",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "~1.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "~1.6.3",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "~2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^1.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "~2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-video-capture-plus": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-video-player": "git+https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "~2.0.3",
    "engine.io-client": "^3.1.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "has-binary": "^0.1.7",
    "ionic": "^4.1.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
    "ionic-image-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^1.3.4",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "isobject": "^3.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "parseuri": "0.0.5",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^7.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "~1.10.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
    "signature_pad": "^2.3.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.3",
    "socket.io-parser": "^3.1.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "to-array": "^0.1.4",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.4.6",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.62",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.29",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "694054568313"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "com.moust.cordova.videoplayer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-battery-status": {}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have multiple versions of the plugin installed - 4.3.3 & 6.0.0

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
ionic cordova platform add android
```

If you need a specific version of the plugin, you can it at the end of the add command as

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file@6.0.0`